# How to check if Option key is down when user clicks a NSButton

Tags: objective-c, nsbutton

I have a few checkboxes along with textfields on a NSPanel that opens to get user parameters.
As an option, I'd like the user to be able to set/unset all the checkboxes on the panel by holding the option key when they press any of the checkboxes.

I'm not sure where/how to check what the key board is doing when the user clicks the button.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

check [[NSEvent modifierFlags]](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSEvent/modifierFlags)...

```
if ([NSEvent modifierFlags ] & NSAlternateKeyMask)
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: This was indeed true and a great approach up to Monterey, but I'm seeing modifierFlags always be 0 on Ventura; details [on a sample project I provided today to Apple for FB11723708](https://github.com/cdf1982/ModifierFlagsChecker).

Comment: pretty interesting @cdf1982 ... just wondering if you check the even being passed into the action rather than NSEvent.currentEvent if it is different... I don't have Ventura on anything yet so I can't really poke around...

Comment: I didn't think of checking the event passed into `mouseDown:`, thank you @GradyPlayer! Sadly, it's the same event as `NSApp.currentEvent`, but it was worth a try. I'm exploring, with a bit of repulsion, the idea of importing Carbon and then use `GetCurrentKeyModifiers()`, as that method is returning "512" each time Shift is down, which is what I'm trying to check. Adding a Carbon import at the end of 2022 sounds less than ideal, but for a temporary fix...

Comment: On macOS Monterey 12.6.1 (21G215) I have found a workaround: just add !0 and it works again. BOOL altKeyPressed = ([event modifierFlags ] & NSEventModifierFlagOption) != 0;

Answer (score 6):

Just my 2c, a Swift 3 version:

```swift
if NSEvent.modifierFlags().contains(NSEventModifierFlags.command) {
    print("Bingo")
}
```

One can see the rest of the flags in the documentation for `NSEventModifierFlags`.

Answer (score 1):

Update: `NSAlternateKeyMask` is now deprecated. Use `NSEventModifierFlagOption` instead.

See [NSEventModifierFlags](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nseventmodifierflags?language=objc) for a complete overview about all modifier flags.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5 - Also helps distinguish between the "up" and "down" presses of Option key

```
override func flagsChanged(with event: NSEvent) {
    print(event)
    
    if event.keyCode == 58 && event.modifierFlags.contains(NSEvent.ModifierFlags.option){
        print("Option Key is down!")
    }
    else if(event.keyCode == 58)
    {
        print("Option Key is up!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's for someone who using swift and struggling with this.

```
if NSEvent.modifierFlags.rawValue & NSEvent.ModifierFlags.command.rawValue != 0 {
    // to do something.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 2.2:

```
if NSEvent.modifierFlags().contains(.AlternateKeyMask) {
    print("Option key pressed")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On macOS 10.14, when called from a NSGestureRecognizerDelegate method in ObjC, `[NSEvent modifierFlags]` was always returning 0 for me, regardless of what keys were down. I was able to reliably work around this by using `[NSApp currentEvent]` instead of `NSEvent`.

```
- (BOOL)isOptionKeyDown {
    NSEventModifierFlags keyEventFlags = [[NSApp currentEvent] modifierFlags] & NSEventModifierFlagDeviceIndependentFlagsMask;
    return (keyEventFlags & NSEventModifierFlagOption) != 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Swift 4:

```
func optionKeyPressed() -> Bool
{        
    let optionKey = NSEvent.modifierFlags.contains(NSEvent.ModifierFlags.option)
    return optionKeyPressed
}

if optionKeyPressed()
{
    print ("option key pressed")
}
```